# how to use cancel button in registration?

Tags: asp.net, validation

In my registration webpage,5 textboxes with required and regular expression validators.click register button means it show all validators properly but suppose click cancel button means it remove the text in all textboxes watever filled.but it showing the validators to fill all the textboxes after filled values in all textbox it allow to remove all text in textboxes otherwise wont...how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `CausesValidation="False"`  on the cancel button

Comment: @giri: you have to accept the ans. if its working.. so for the next time this may help for other

Comment: k sorry.can u please tel me how to assign the textbox that possible way to give only ten digits in that textbox?

Comment: string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload.FileName); string Imagename = objUser.UserID + filename; FileUpload.SaveAs(@"D:\Shop_Web_21-6-12\ShopMonkey\Images" + Imagename); uploaded file is not stored in given physical path?above is my coding..